# How to refresh the laravel pagination when using ajax filtering data

Tags: ajax, laravel, pagination

I am using custom filter to filter my data in a div content

```
<div id="refresh">
<div/>

// pagination 
{{ $lists->links() }}
```

It will displayed all data when display the site.

```
Previous | 1 | 2 | 3 | Next
```

After i filter data, the content will be refreshed but the pagination still remain unchanged.

```
Previous | 1 | 2 | 3 | Next
```

It should be 2 pages, since data filtered only 2 pages but it shows 3 pages.

```
Previous | 1 | 2 | Next
```

I am using ajax to filter the data by refreshing the content data. It works fine but just the pagination do not update. Any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Put the pagination block inside the `<div id="refresh">`

Comment: If do so, the content css style will missing when paginate to another pages.

Comment: You would have to update the links using javascript. You would need to use the `last page` and `current_page` properties from the response to calculate what links should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use**

```
<div id="refresh">
 <div/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#refresh').load(document.URL + ' #refresh');                  
        }, 1000)
    </script>
```